# Interpret JDBC connection

Tags: java, oracle11g, datasource, oracle-xe

I want to understand the basics of connection to Data Sources.
Using Weblogic, if I want to connect to a DataSource, how do I interpret the URL;

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
```

Also when we specify Username/Password, is that for the entire database?

I am using Oracle 11g XE.

Like what part represents what in this URL?

Comment: Hope [this](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC) helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are communicating over the network, you need following three basic things

1. Protocol
2. Host
3. Resource

Typical example would be

> http://docs.oracle.com/index.html

Where
http - protocol

docs.oracle.com - host

index.html the resource

Similarly other example would be

> ftp://public.ftp-servers.example.com/mydirectory/myfile.txt

So in general, a resource can be represented over the network as follows

> [PROTOCOL]:[HOST][RESOURCES]

Extending the same to the JDBC URL you have mentioned

> jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE

**jdbc:oracle:thin** - specifies **protocol** which in turn indicate which driver is to  be used. So every driver has its own protocol to communicate with database server.

**localhost:1521** - is Host

**XE**- is the resource which is to be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

Connection string definition

```
 jdbc:oracle:thin:[USER/PASSWORD]@[HOST][:PORT]:SID
```

Answer (score 1):

`jdbc:oracle:thin` specifies Oracle's JDBC Thin driver.

`@localhost` is the hostname , the DB server machine.

`1521` post at which the server runs.

`XE` may be a oracle service name or a SID, defined in *tnsnames.ora* file

You can specify the usernam/password also :

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:[USER/PASSWORD]@//[HOST][:PORT]/SERVICE
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you the [JDBC Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html%20JDBC%20tutorial) and more precisely [Java DB Database Connection URLs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html#db_connection_url%20Java%20DB%20Database%20Connection%20URLs)

jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE

jdbc: part defines the protocol

oracle:thin part defines the driver

@localhost defines server address (here localhost, can be an IP address or host name)

1521 defines the remote port

XE defines the SID of the database

> Also when we specify Username/Password, is that for the entire database?

you will have access to what is available to the user you provided, so it depends on the database configuration